Minimum Spanning Tree, Standard for determining weight
I am a student studying the minimum spanning tree algorithm.
If you look at it, the concept of weight appears between graphs. By what standard is this weight determined?
“In reality, the distance from home to school and the distance from home to the supermarket are different.”
Rather than an abstract story that only understands this methodology.
Exactly what criteria do you use to determine the weight value?
I am a student studying the minimum spanning tree algorithm.

I don't understand the question. For a weighted graph, the weights are known. See Wikipedia - weighted graph

That is up to you what weights you assign to the edges. It's meaning dependes on the meaning of the graph. Usually graph represents some geological points connected by roads, like cities etc ... The meaning of the weight is than proportional to distances of the points.
It's a mathematical model of a real life problem you would like to solve. Minimum spanning tree was original used for contructing electrical grids in Czech republic by Otakar Borůvka. The desire was to get electricity to as many cities without redundant wirings, to save uneeded costs. More on that here.
